# Serve static resource via one instance of a web application in a clustered environment

Tags: java, servlets

I am working on an application that is deployed on a cluster of JBoss servers accessible via a load balancer. There is a set of data originating from another external service that I would like to expose as part of my application. But since this service is load sensitive, I would like to call this service from a separate standalone Java application only from one instance on regular intervals and put the data in a file which will be statically accessible over HTTP by the container itself. However, since this file will exist only one instance, if a request is routed to any other instance in that cluster, it will result in a 404 File Not Found. So this means that I need to make this file accessible on all instances.

One approach that I was considering was to have a servlet with the servlet mapping url pattern exactly as the file name that will hold the data. If the instance on which a request lands is the one instance where the file exists, it should serve the file or else it should be picked up by the servlet with the same url pattern as the file which will fetch the file from the one instance where the file exists and return that in response.

However, when I use the same url pattern for a servlet as a static file, the servlet is picked up first and the static resource is not looked up at all. Is there a way I can tell the webapp to look for the static resource first before looking up the servlet?

Second approach that I could think of was to use a filter with the same url pattern that will check for the existence of the file and if the file exists, let the container handle it or else get the file from instance where this file exists and return the same back in the response.

Can you think of any other approaches and the pros and cons of each before I decide which approach to take forward?